# Checking Parse password

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, passwords

I want to make my applications password changing process a little more secure so that not just anybody can go on to an account and change their password, so my question is:

Is there a way to compare the password in a Parse database to what is entered in a text field? If the "Old Password" text field does not match the information in the database they will not be able to save their changes unless they get it correct. Is this possible? I know Parse encrypts passwords so I am not sure if this is possible and I have found no evidence in my search.

Comment: Why not use 

    [PFUser requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground:@"email@example.com"];

Then this would send an email to the user with a link to reset the password.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe this is possible to do. Even if you try to retrieve the user's password the result is an empty string. A workaround could be to try to log the user in again (in the background), which I think Parse allows you to do, and if the log in is successful..well then the password was right! Let me know if you can achieve what you want with this.